# Rails, strong parameters, partly required

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I'm using CarrierWave and to be able to remove a picture, I need to permit parameter which isn't a part of user:

```
params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :description, :picture, :remove_picture)
```

It gives me errors, but changing it to:

```
params.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :description, :picture, :remove_picture)
```

as suggested in one of topics on forum, gives errors too - "unpermitted parameters commit, id" etc. How can I require user and in the same time - permit remove_picture?

Answer (score 2):

You should nest the `remove_picture` attribute under user like in the example in the [readme](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#removing-uploaded-files):

```
<%= form_for @user, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
  <p>
    <label>My Avatar</label>
    <%= image_tag(@user.avatar_url) if @user.avatar? %>
    <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <label>
      <%= f.check_box :remove_avatar %>
      Remove avatar
    </label>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

That would let you do

```
params.require(:user)
      .permit(:first_name, :last_name, :description, :picture, :remove_picture)
```

The Rails mass assignment protection is basically just hash slicing:

- `.require` pulls a single key from the hash and raises an error if its not there.
- `.permit` returns the keys which are allowed and marks the hash as safe for mass assignment.

Its made to handle a hash nested under a single param key or at the root. While you can go crazy merging two hashes:

```
p = params.require(:user)
          .permit(:first_name, :last_name, :description, :picture)
p.merge!(params.permit(:remove_picture))
```

You are just creating problems for yourself.

Comment: Thank you for long answer, but I realized my problem is different. My image upload works fine, but when I click on "add avatar" without selecting file to be attached, I get "param is missing or the value is empty: user". Only parameters sent are utf8, method, authenticity_token, commit, id (but id without 'user' key). I set redirection in my controller, but it works only when 'user' is not required.  I must find a way to not require user, but requiring him in the same time...

Comment: You can use `params.fetch(:user, {}).permit(:a,:b,:c)`. But you should just look at the examples in the readme and nest the inputs properly. This is very likely an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) where your form is messed up but you are overly concentrated on using strong params to finagle around the problem. The end result is a inconsistent API.

 If you can't get it work add your form and controller to the question.